# Typescript make the second parameter type depends on the first parameter type

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
enum Channel {
  GITHUG = 'github',
  GITLAB = 'gitlab',
}

interface Github {}

interface Gitlab {}

function foo (a, b) {}
```

The first parameter **a** is an enum (Channel) value

If parameter **a** is github, then the type of **b** is GitHub

If parameter **a** is gitlab, then the type of **b** is Gitlab

How to define the type of function **foo**?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads?

Answer (score 4):

Here you have some alternative ways:

```js
enum Channel {
  GITHUB = 'github',
  GITLAB = 'gitlab',
}

interface Github {
  type: 'Github'
}

interface Gitlab {
  type: 'Gitlab'
}

/**
 * First approach
 */
type Params = [Channel.GITHUB, Github] | [Channel.GITLAB, Gitlab]

function foo(...args: Params) {
  if (args[0] === Channel.GITHUB) {
    const x = args[1] // Github
  }
}


type Overloading =
  & ((a: Channel.GITHUB, b: Github) => void)
  & ((a: Channel.GITLAB, b: Gitlab) => void)


/**
 * Second approach
 */

const foo2: Overloading = (a: Channel, b: Github | Gitlab) => null as any

const result = foo2(Channel.GITHUB, { type: 'Github' }) // ok


/**
 * Third approach
 */
function foo3(a: Channel.GITLAB, b: Gitlab): void
function foo3(a: Channel.GITHUB, b: Github): void
function foo3(a: Channel, b: Github | Gitlab) {

}
foo3(Channel.GITLAB, { type: 'Gitlab' }) // ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAwgFgQxCYAbKBvAsAKClAcQEkAVACQFUAhKAXigHIBzASwBc4wAjBgGl3zESAGQCCNes3aoEPfjgC%20uXCxBtgAJwBmCAMbBC7Tl0wCobAJ4AHYAC5GBI9wa4lOFWs079htjJPYeObWdg7Ssi6KyjgA9ABUcQJxUABiLBoAzmxQCFZWGgD2enBJMbiWNlAACggaCBAZdFAA2vBIKKgAdEKUVLy%20xgC6UAA%20LW3IaN2kYn2%20-oPRWmAgumwsBSBQWgUFABSdh7VMGfY1dQ0AlKZBLFpQe8cZzQAMw7QfsIiTXT3U14F8PhdJsslAAB5NJ7NACMwxiMQG3DMbjc0QqBgA8gA3TSoIoAE1UTDoZgAZA9HvYJh1puRqP0uPZHBxuNdaAA%20KDYgosAmXcmUhDU760oSzRnM8Jcdlcnl8gXuJXxRJ4ZIAZWAIJABJyeUKxVK0W1YJ2BQATPYcXjCcSmlSvu00JKkSYxiz-LKoOBUOgEI0kBZjaDshpgBkwKhsvQzea9jSpn85hhgjZ7AwWcYGFAFNcEVACgBraK4FVJKAkODpXW5fJFXQlNVlHDLVbrTbbXYAZgdCd%20M3ELo9sku9nlBNwrbWGy2Zp7wsdPzpvSHThlY95E5bK2nHbnvdFzqgTNdo3mI5urkn3fjh-7IkHmFToQz0uzuag%20aLQA)

Answer (score 2):

Use [conditional types technique](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html). Look at example below or go to online [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAwgFgQxCYAbKBvAUFKBxASQBUAJAVTygF4oByAcwEsAXOMAI1oBod9iAZAIIAhanSbNUCTjwC%20WLIxDNgAJwBmCAMbB8LNu0y8A%20uoD2ZgFxRwEdmqzzFytZp17J0o7mPsEq61t7VUcFZgBPAAddAAV-BAgiKOAAHhgAPjEYKGAADxUQABMAZ1hEZDQAOkJSCigAfg8DKGs8Fil2AG4sdTAQLWZGMxAoczM0nPzQErKkFFR0gAoEaxguKHZrONUEpOi09IBKawA3M0ZCzCcxxfg5qpqhYXWMKFMLawBGKFlDzqgAPQAnKqVRmEI3O4VVDVAQiF5vPwBKDfX7-IFQYpgLQ6YrFLBAA) in order to test in action (thanks for help to [Joonas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13065068/joonas))

```
enum Channel {
  GITHUG = 'github',
  GITLAB = 'gitlab',
}

interface Github {
  _foo: number
}

interface Gitlab {
  _bar: number
}

type ParamType<C> = C extends Channel.GITHUG ? Github : Gitlab;
function foo<C extends Channel>(a: C, b: ParamType<C>): void {}

foo(Channel.GITLAB, { _foo: 1 }); // error
foo(Channel.GITLAB, { _bar: 1 }); // success
```

[image]

---

Please, let me know if it works or not )

Comment: This doesn't use Github and Gitlab interfaces at all. `ParamType` should be defined in terms of the first argument, i.e. [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAwgFgQxCYAbKBvAUFKBxASQBUAJAVTygF4oByAcwEsAXOMAI1oBod9iAZAIIAhanSbNUCTjwC+WLIxDNgAJwBmCAMbB8LNu0y8A+uoD2ZgFxRwEdmqzzFytZp17J0o7mPsEq61t7VUcFZgBPAAddAAV-BAgiKOAAHhgAPjEYKGAADxUQABMAZ1hEZDQAOkJSCigAfg8DKGs8Fil2AG4sdTAQLWZGMxAoczM0nPzQErKkFFR0gAoEaxguKHZrONUEpOi09IBKawA3M0ZCzCcxxfg5qpqhYXWMKFMLawAWACYoWUPOlAAPRAnKqVRmEI3O4VVDVAQiF5vPwBKA-P4A4Gg4pgLQ6YrFLBAA)

Comment: @Joonas thanks for help. I missed that part )

Answer (score 1):

Explain look at the code comments:

```
enum Channel {
  GITHUG = 'github',
  GITLAB = 'gitlab',
}

interface Github {}

interface Gitlab {}

// Map enum value and type
interface Foo {
  github: Github
  gitlab: Gitlab
}

// `${Channel}` => 'github' | 'gitlab'
// Get the type K of a through the passed parameter
// if K is `github`, Foo[K] is Github
// if k is `gitlab`, Foo[K] is Gitlab
function foo<K extends `${Channel}`>(a: K, b: Foo[K]) {}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAwgFgQxCYAbKBvAsAKClAcQEkAVACQFUCoBeKAcgHMBLAFzjACN6AaXfYiQAyAQQBCtBi1aoE3PjgC%20uXMxCtgAJwBmCAMbBCbDp0z98UBAC4oAZ1aa1jXMpyr1W3QaMy5ZvBacNvaOIM5KKjhqGjr6hgBiAPaJ-vjSJjYExlzm0rJBPvkukdpgIHqszIkgUNrJADwA0lDAAB4aIAAmtlAABgAkGPBIKKiKvQB8ABTWUI08UAVJiQDajQC6AJSYrrh61fZQjHCZ2aZ0GJY29PRQrvsgh4yop77nmIvXt7s4dYlTTDOvCOcE2QA)

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem, in my case, the second parameter type comes from an interface:

```js
interface ArgTypes { [id: string]: any }
interface ChannelArgs extends ArgTypes{
  github: {
    hubhub: number
  },
  gitlab: {
    lablab: number
  },
  ...
}
type Arg<Args extends ArgTypes, Id extends keyof Args> = Args[Id]
```

My `foo` function has to work with all types implementing the interface, so it is generic itself:

```js
foo<ChannelArgs>('github', {hubhub: 12})
```

Turns out, declaration of a generic type and an inferred type does not mix, but it is possible to put them in different brackets:

```js
type Foo<Args extends ArgTypes> = <Id extends keyof Args>(
  id: Id,
  arg: Arg<Args, Id>
) => void

const gitFoo: Foo<ChannelArgs> = function(a,b): void {}

gitFoo('github', {hubhub: 12}) // no error
gitFoo('github', {lablab: 12}) // error
```